# How to work with NetBeans and Tomcat, when the Tomcat address is different from "127.0.0.1" and the hostname is different from "localhost"?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I need to change the address and port to access the Tomcat 7.0.42 to use with NetBeans 8.0.1 on Windows 7.

Then, I changed the following line on the server.xml file:

```
<Connector address="127.0.0.70" connectionTimeout="20000" port="7080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="7443"/>
```

(I've changed the other port references, too.)

I also changed the windows hosts file (I know... that's not a good idea, if you don't know what you are doing) by adding the following line:

```
127.0.0.70    tomcat7042
```

It works fine if I start the Tomcat server from the command line ("startup.bat") and access the gui through the link

```
http://tomcat7042:7080
```

However, if I try to start the Tomcat from the NetBeans I get the message "Start of Tomcat failed". Actually, the NetBeans doesn't recognize that the server is running, even if it was started up from the command line.

One interesting thing is that when the server is started (and failed) from the NetBeans  the console shows the message "Server startup in 14082 ms" and the process for the Tomcat is started. Then, I have to kill the process to try to run the Tomcat again.

Another interesting point is that the mouseover on the server name (apache-tomcat-7.0.42) in the NetBeans, shows the tip "http:// localhost:7080" which is different from the server.xml configuration.

Then, the question: how to work with NetBeans and Tomcat, when the Tomcat address is different from "127.0.0.1" and the hostname is different from "localhost"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: Hi, @Stefan. Actually, I don't have problems with the "localhost" configuration. The problem is when I try to use the NetBeans with a non-standard localhost configuration.